# VM's share disk images

Tags: vmware-esxi

The current situation is this:

```
1x ESXi 4.1 host with:
    1x VM: main win2k8 server (hostname: fs01)
    physical disk 1 (250GB) -> datastore 1 (200GB) -> vmdisk with OS of VM's
    physical disk 2 (250GB) -> datastore 2 (200GB) -> vmdisk with files
    physical disk 3 (500GB) -> datastore 3 (500GB) -> vmdisk with files
    physical disk 4 (  1TB) -> not configured yet

fs01 configuration:
    datastore 1 -> C:\ ( 40GB) -> OS
    datastore 2 -> D:\ (200GB) -> shares (\\fs01\users\public; \\fs01\users\%username%)
    datastore 3 -> E:\ (500GB) -> shares (\\fs01\media)
```

`fs01` has file shares on `datastore 2` and `datastore 3`.

What I wish is to have a fallback VM `fs02` configured exactly like `fs01` that uses the vmdisk images on `datastore 2` and `datastore 3` from `fs01`. So that if `fs01` crashes or fails to start `fs02` will boot up and make the file shares available to me.

I don't even know if ESXi can check whether or not `fs01` has booted properly, but I'm guessing it does have a way of checking if it's on or not. And if not have ESXi startup `fs02` automatically.

My clients have mappings to the shared folders of `fs01`, and I won't mind if the mappings aren't available because `fs01` crashed. As long as I can have `fs02` boot up automatically so the shared folders become available by directly addressing them. (like `\\fs02\users\public`; `\\fs02\media`)

So `fs01` and `fs02` share the disk images located in `datastore 2` and `datastore 3`.

Questions:

1. Can ESXi check if `fs01` has started and if not start `fs02`?
2. Can `fs01` and `fs02` share the same disk images from the datastores?

Comment: Your home network scenario here represents something wholly contrived, in terms of the applicability to professional systems administration. Nobody would do this on a real business network.

Comment: I know Evan Anderson. But I've got to work with whatever I have lying around in the house ;). And although I'd rather build a 4+ core system with 32GB RAM, 8 SSD's, RAID 6, ESXi 5+, running 3 Win2012 servers, 2 Win7 VMs with RDP and a 8 slot tape backup... I have to make do with my AMD Athlon 64 3500+, 4GB RAM, and 4 disks. I'm just glad it can run one VM! It's not even build into a server case. Just a regular midi-tower. (which is a good thing, noise wise). But yeah no sysadmin would build something like this...ever! :p
I just use it to familiarize myself with ESXi and VM's.

Comment: No, this is craziness. It's not the way to do failover. If you're concerned about stability, buying better hardware is going to take you much farther than some horrible VMDK-sharing situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VMWare [FT](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.availability.doc_41/c_plan_understand_ft.html), so that if fs01 fails, it automatically enables fs02. Might be worth reading [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1034165).

Comment: My reputation (less than 15) doesn't allow me to upvote this yet, but it's +1 just for being quick in coming up with useful info.

Comment: VMWare FT requires a 2nd host machine, which I don't have unless I convert my desktop to be one. And I think the wife wouldn't be happy about it. But the item about multi-write was very helpful. Now my only concern is that running 2 VM's simultaneously on my ESXi machine might be a little too much for it, reducing performance in a way that the file shares become unavailable. I'm still trying to figure out how many VM's I could run simultaneously on this machine => AMD Athlon 64 3500+, 4GB RAM

Comment: This answer is just wrong, too... Especially given the scenario the OP described.